# EFI Windows Bootloader Recovery

Tags: windows, uefi, efi, partition-recovery, recovery-partition

i deleted windows boot loader in efi instead of ubuntu by mistake.
Now i am left with ubuntu without windows. Is there a way to fix the windows boot loader from ubuntu terminal as i couldn't open windows anymore.

Comment: i solved it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Download Windows image from the Microsoft Website and Change the Boot order and load the windows installation setup. If you have your own recovery drive then use that.
Select repair instead of installation and go to the command prompt
As other answers suggested in boot repair, create a temporary volume name for EFI drive.

`diskpart`

Go to EFI drive and do reparation work
For me  /fixmbr there didnt work so i tried

`bcdboot d:\windows /s m: /f all`

which worked.
Always use windows copy command (ubuntu cp eq) to copy efi partition to another drive before doing these to avoid mistakes hich can furhter harm the system